# How come that HSL can contain more information than RGB?

Tags: linear-algebra, information-theory, coloring

I have noticed weird thing when working with HSL - unlike RGB, it has some *blind spots* where certain value just does not matter. I'm sure we were taught about this when I had Linear algebra lectures about Linear space transformations.

Say RGB(r,g,b) and HSL(h,s,l) are both vectors. Now every value of RGB produces different color. It's a space of a cube and every point is different:

[image: RGB cube]

HSL is not this case. For $s=0$ or $l \in \{0,1\}$ the value of $h$ does not matter. And specifically in case $l \in \{0,1\}$ nothing matters. In other words some HSL vectors project into same RGB vector. There was a term in the linear algebra for this situation.

There is a 3D plot for HSL too:
[image: HSL cone]

But in fact, you can also reference values that are out of this cone - they are just not included because they are the same colors.

I was mostly thinking about this because it occurred to me to have an idea that maybe 3 coordinates are too much for color system that uses hue. Could there be one angle for color and one for both saturation and lightness without excluding any colors?

Could you explain me how come that three coordinates can contain different amounts of information?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Since HSL and RGB can be interconverted, they can only represent the same things. I don't think it's different from $x, y, z$ (cartesian) and $r, \theta, \phi$ (polar) coordinates in geometry - you just use the one which is more convenient.

Comment: You don't have two different polar coordinates that project into same cartesian one. And if you do, I want to know why the polar space is bigger than the cartesian if it can contain whole cartesian and even have some extra values that produce same cartesian coordinates.

Comment: Yes you do, for example at the poles $\theta$ is irrelevant.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_space We have different colour *spaces* with different colour *models* here

Comment: @SuzuHirose Well, then how can it be so that some coordinates are irrelevant if there's same amount of coordinates? That's the question. Maybe it's just such an obvious thing you never thought about it...

Answer (score 1):

Both RGB and HSL denote colours as coordinates in a 3D space. That the correspondence is not strictly one-to-one can be understood by thinking of the the analogy (pointed out in comments) of the two common ways of specifying points in the 2D space: **cartesian** vs **polar** (and, indeed, if we think of the RGB space as cartesian coordinates, both [HSL and HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) should be thought as **cylindrical** coordinates). Both cartesian and polar coordinates contains the same amount of information, but in the polar coordinates, for the case $r=0$ the value of the angle $\phi$ does not matter - so, in that sense you could argue that the cartesian coordinate $(x=0,y=0)$ maps to a full set of polar coordinates $(r=0,\phi)$. I don't think that this fact would imply that one coordinate system has "more information" than the other.

Perhaps you are thinking in terms of quantized representations, such that, for example, we have 8 bits for each "channel" - in this discrete space, RGB would allow for $256^3$ different colours, while if we do the same for HSL, we'd get fewer colours. That's true, but it's rather irrelevant.

Comment: You can have a HSV [25,0,0] coordinate. As you convert the color to RGB, the information about hue is lost. In the color it doesn't matter. But in a special case it might. RGB doesn't have such a problem - no coordinate value is ever lost when converting to RGB.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. That's for me the same as saying "when you convert the point in polar $(r=0,\phi=45^{\circ})$ to cartesian coordinates, the angle information is lost." Actually, that "angle" has no information, the points .$(r=0,\phi=45^{\circ})$ and $(r=0,\phi=60^{\circ})$ are the same.

Comment: The points are, but the numbers ain't. That's what's troubling me: how come you've got yourself a number that doesn't matter as long as you switch to using angles.

Comment: "The points are, but the numbers ain't" What matters are the points. Another example: the fraction 1/2 can be converted to the decimal 0.5 and viceversa; but also 2/4 (and 4/8) is converted to 0.5. Would you say here that "the numbers are lost", that we are somehow losing information, when going from one of those fractions to the decimal representation?